# How to salt potatoes?

Tags: salt, potatoes

I would use boiled or fried potatoes inside other recipes like the [Spanish tortilla](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_omelette) which has usually a salty taste. Depending on how I cut the potatoes however, sometimes there is too much contrast between how salty mix and the potato chunks.

I wonder if there is a way I could salt the potatoes correctly before adding them to de mixture.

For instance, for the tortilla I mention, the spuds are cooked in olive oil for about 30min. Adding salt to the oil while cooking had little effect. I was thinking about leaving them in salty water for a while, but that would take a long time and pre-boiling it, doesn't seem to fit the recipe.. so..?

Comment: Are you salting the potatoes after they've been fried, or only salting the egg mixture?  I've never had a problem, but I also keep my potato cut rather thinly, so there's not a large volume of interior potato that would be unseasoned.

Comment: I usually add salt to the cooked potatoes and to the egg mixture. Thinking of it, it might have to do with the thickness I'm cutting it. Will make some try.. though was really wondering if there was a better way to do it.

Comment: Janet Mendel's *Cooking In Spain* directs you to salt the egg mixture before adding it to the pan, and not the potatoes at all.  That seems likely to just perpetuate the flavor contrast you don't like though.

Comment: I'm with Joe. How thick do you cut your potatoes?

Comment: As an aside - should never add salt to anything while it is in oil... Salt will dramatically hasten the break down of oils when the oil is at a high temperature.

Comment: I have been doing some experiments and it all seems to come down to how tick i am using the potatoes. @FuzzyChef, mind that the contrast is not completely undesired, in fact I add the onions to get the sweet contrast. It is just that when using too tick spuds you'd get to feel the blandness of it against the tasty mix. thiner slices (about 1 to 3mm, before I was using something like 2-4mm) seems to always mix in perf.

Comment: @mrwienerdog that sounds very interesting. What does oil break down means? less taste?

Comment: @filippo : it actually gives it more taste, but not necessarily good.  And it also lowers the smoke point.

Answer (score 2):

Add the salt in te bowl of egg and potato mixture, right before pouring the mix to the pan. You don't salt the potatoes you salt the whole tortilla.

Even if you use onion. The onion inside the Spanish tortilla tastes always sweet.

[image: tortilla de patatas - paso 7]